# How to correctly subtract time in AM and PM in shell script?

Tags: shell-script, timestamps

I am facing a situation where suppose I subtract 01:00:00 AM and 23:00:00 PM using my below script I am getting a difference of 21 hours when it is only 2 hours.

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/sh

Tm1=$(echo `date +%H:%M:%S`)
T1=`date -d "$Tm1" +%r`
X1=$(echo $T1 | awk -F: '{print ($1 *3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3}')

Tm2=$(cat $DIR/session_$DATE.txt | awk '{print $5}' | head -1)
T2=`date -d "$Tm2" +%r`
X2=$(echo $T2 | awk -F: '{print ($1 *3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3}')

diff=$(($X1-$X2))


TimeDifference=$(echo print $diff/3600. | python)
echo $TimeDifference
```

Is there a way to achieve this? Please suggest.

EDIT:

$DIR/session_$DATE.txt

it's a netezza session file with similar lines like below. Showing only first line below:

```
26195 sql-odbc XXX  27-May-21 01:18:51 CDT
```

Comment: What's in `$DIR/session_$DATE.txt`?

Comment: "Adding X and Y" makes sense.  Addition is commutative.  "Subtracting X and Y" does not.  You need to stipulate the minuend and the subtrahend.

Comment: In the absence of the date that goes with each time, the difference is *both* 2 hours and 22 hours. See "Groundhog Day".

Comment: Thanks Paul. It works now after adding date!

Comment: as an aside, instead of `Tm1=$(echo \`date +%H:%M:%S\`)`, which is the same as `Tm1=$(echo $(date +%H:%M:%S) )`, you could just skip the `echo` and use `Tm1=$(date +%H:%M:%S)`.

Answer (score 1):

There's so many things wrong with your script that it's hard to know where to begin.  I'll settle for "you're making this way more complicated than it needs to be".

From looking at your script, it seems that you want to know the number of hours between a) the date & time in a logfile and b) now.  Therefore:

1. you need the current date and time in seconds-since-the-epoch(*) format.

   ```
   X1="$(date +%s)"
   ```
2. you need the date and time extracted from the first line of the session log file, also converted to seconds since the epoch.

   ```
   X2="$(date -d "$(awk 'NR==1 {print $(NF-2),$(NF-1),$NF; nextfile}' session.txt)" +%s)"
   ```
3. You need to calculate the difference between those two dates (X1-X2), in hours (/3600).

   ```
   let diff=(X1-X2)/3600
   ```

Example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# get current time
X1="$(date +%s)"

# get the date, time, and timezone from the last 3 fields of the first line
logfile=session.txt
X2="$(date -d "$(awk 'NR==1 {print $(NF-2),$(NF-1),$NF; nextfile}' "$logfile")" +%s)"

# calculate the difference in hours.  Note that bash arithmetic is integer only,
# so the result of the division is automatically rounded down.
let diff=(X1-X2)/3600

echo $diff
```

(*) for historical reasons, the "epoch" is defined as Midnight Jan 1, 1970.  "01-01-1970 00:00:00".   It doesn't really matter when it is, it's a convenient common reference point for doing date and time calculations using seconds.

Comment: More precisely, the Unix epoch is defined as 00:00:00 UTC (Coordinated Universal Time) on  January 1st, 1970.  However, Unix time treats days as if they contains exactly 86400 seconds. Thus Unix time is not a true representation of UTC.

Comment: Yep.  A simple approximation like this is good enough for simple purposes only.  If exact times and dates (including leap years and seconds, DST transitions, etc) are important, then use a language with a good date & time calculation library.  perl's [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) module with [DateTime::Timezone](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::TimeZone), for example (which takes into account current and historical time zone data & daylight saving rules).